# how to generate XML sitemap with special symbols in the link?

Tags: xml, sitemap

Hi
I am trying to generate google sitemap for my site,
how can i make link to contain special symbols like below:

```
<url>
   <loc>http://example.com/alf-“xxx-yyy”--cache</loc>
</url>
```

how can i handle such characters??? i have tried urlencode but this doesn't work :((
Thanks for your help

Comment: How about just using an existing library, for example: https://github.com/refinery29/sitemap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special characters that you are referring to are the directional curly quotes `“` and `”`. You can use the numeric entity reference for those characters `&#8220;` and `&#8221;`, respectively.

http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/quotes-in-html.html

> If you’re creating HTML, SGML, and XML
>   directly, perhaps using a text editor
>   or writing a program, always use
>   “decimal numeric character references”
>   for curling single and double quote
>   characters (these marks are called
>   “smart quotes,” “curly quotes,”
>   “curled quotes,” “curling quotes,” or
>   “curved quotes”).
>
> **In other words, for
>   left and right double quotation marks,
>   use `&#8220;` and `&#8221;`** - and for left
>   and right single quotation marks (and
>   apostrophes), use `&#8216;` and `&#8217;`
>   - and you’ll be glad you did. This approach complies with all
>   international standards, and works
>   essentially everywhere.

```
Left Double Quotation Mark   =   &#8220; = “
Right Double Quotation Mark =   &#8221; = ”
Left Single Quotation Mark   =   &#8216; = ‘
Right Single Quotation Mark =   &#8217; = ’
```

> By doing this, your text will look
>   good on a very wide variety of
>   browsers and viewers, and you can
>   easily cut-and-paste portions of data
>   between HTML, SGML, and XML documents
>   (letting you dynamically query and
>   create new material from existing
>   material, without having to deal with
>   the complexities of translating
>   between character sets).

Answer (score 1):

XML has five [predefined entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-predefined-ent).

In your example, you need to represent the quotes as `&quot;`.

`<url>`
   `<loc>http://example.com/alf-&quot;xxx-yyy&quot;--cache</loc>`
`</url>`