# French symbol "é" in sitemap links not reading

Tags: special-characters, sitemap, google-search-console

My sitemap have links with special characters of languages, like russian letters, and so on. 
Still i have problem with only french "é" (Hex code point 00E9). Google web master tools tells me that i have an 404 error in my sitemap for links with this symbol. It cuts the part of link after this symbol. For example: i have a link like

```
example.com/décembre
```

so it returns 404 error from link

```
example.com/d
```

What the solution to avoid such errors, and what other symbols not valid for google sitemaps?
May i use this solution and write `example.com/d&#00e9;cembre` ? [how to generate XML sitemap with special symbols in the link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483340/how-to-generate-xml-sitemap-with-special-symbols-in-the-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"é" is not a valid character inside a URL. URLs exclusively consist of a subset of ASCII characters. The character must be [*URL encoded*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to be used inside a URL, e.g. to `%C3%A9` if you're inclined to use UTF-8.

Comment: So why it passes russian symbols then?

Comment: Does it? Where?

Comment: You right, it's not. Was confused coz in my links with russain symbols - result of cutting part of link after first russian symbol still returns valid link, so it's not 404. It's strange that validation of sitemap with all these symbols is valid, no error about bad symbols, i'm lucky about this french symbol that helps me to find out the problem. Thank's for answer.